# Best practice to represent bit string in hex (Arduino)

Tags: c++, c, binary, arduino, hex

I have a string (or cstring) consisted of 24 bits "000101011110011110101110" that should be represented in hex (0x15e7ae).

As i understand bit string needs to be splitted on to 6 parts by 4 bits
"0001 0101 1110 0111 1010 1110" and then each part converted to hex

```
0001 -> 1
0101 -> 5
1110 -> e
0111 -> 7
1010 -> a
1110 -> e
```

So what are the simplest and cost effective ways to convert it to hex representation: 0x15e7ae?

There is also dilemma for me which string type is better to use String or char[]. String can be easily splitted using substring function, but i don't know how to convert string type to hex.

And contrariwise char[] can be easily converted to hex using strtoul function but i didn't find simple way to split char string.

Comment: Are you sure that you really mean "convert to hex", because `strtoul` converts to an `unsigned long int`; hexadecimal representation of such an integer may be generated as a string by an output function such as `sprintf` or `printf` for example.  You need to be precise about your actual input and the required output.

Comment: I mean hex representation that can be printed out, doesn't matter what data type it will be.

Comment: Yes, but ideally you need to make that clear in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: changed conversation to representation. No dual meaning now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try some simple bit shifting.

```
std::string sample_str = "000101011110011110101110";
uint32_t result = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sample_str.length(); ++i)
{
  result = result << 1;
  result = result | (sample_str[i] & 1);
}
```

There may be faster methods, but you would have to search the web for "bit twiddling string".

**Background**
This is based on the assumption that the character representation of zero has the least significant bit set to zero.  Likewise the character representation of one has the least significant bit set to one.

The algorithm shifts the result left by one to make room for a new bit value.
Taking the character value and ANDing with 1 results in a value of zero for '0' and one for '1'. This result is ORed into the `result` value, to produce the correct value.

Try single stepping with a debugger to see how it works.

Comment: actually this code doesn't return "15e7ae", i get 1435566 instead

Comment: @user947668 : 1435566 is the decimal representation of 0x15e7ae.  `result` is an integer, you have to choose how you wish to output it.  That was the point in my comment to the question which you appear to have misunderstood.  Several answers given describe output of an integer in hexadecimal representation.

Comment: @user947668: Once you get the string converted into internal representation, it is up to you how you view it.  You could view it as hexadecimal or decimal; the output of the internal representation is left as an exercise. :-)

Comment: Serial.print(result, HEX); works like a charm! thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is quite literally found in this link: [StringConstructors](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringConstructors)

```
 // using an int and a base (hexadecimal):
 stringOne =  String(45, HEX);   
 // prints "2d", which is the hexadecimal version of decimal 45:
 Serial.println(stringOne);
```

Comment: But the required input is a string of '1' and '0' characters, not an integer.

Comment: A string is literally multiple bytes after one another. Do this: Last byte & 0x0F as input for stringconversion. Then last byte & 0xF0  as input for stringconversion. Move to the next byte. Then add the multiple strings together. Not efficient, but it will work. Post a piece of code if you want a decent answer.

Comment: It is not my question, I was merely pointing out that this is not an answer to the question asked.  It could be used as the last part of a solution where my answer used `sprintf()` - but being tagged C, C++ *and* Arduino - there are any number of possibilities!

Comment: I've check and it seems as a good answer as well. It's not universal as suggested by Clifford and Thomas, but it's the most simple. First parameter of String should be binary data type variable, second HEX.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* binary = "000101011110011110101110" ;
char hex[9] = "" ;

uint32_t integer = 0 ;

for( int i = 0; binary[i+1] != '\0'; i++ )
{
    if( binary[i] == '1' )
    {
        integer |= 1 ;
    }
    integer <<= 1 ;
}

sprintf( hex, "0x%06x", integer ) ;
```

Comment: There's no need for an 'if' statement since the last bit is all that is required from the character.  See my answer. :-)

Comment: Yes, I have seen your answer and it makes assumptions about the character codes for of '0' and '1' (i.e. that '0' is even and '1' odd) that while true for the ubiquitous ASCII representation, it is perhaps less clear.  I'll let this stand I think, but your point is noted and agreed.  I doubt the optimisation is significant however.

Answer (score 1):

In C, this is quite simple. Use `strtoumax(binary, 0, 2)` to convert your binary string to an `uintmax_t` and then convert that to a hex string with `sprintf` or `fprintf`.

Comment: eg: `printf("%jx",strtoumax(binary, 0, 2));`